# How does entity framework identify a property in a model as foreign key? dbFirst

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

DBFirst : How does entity framework establish that a property is linked to another model / table. In the example below CustomerId is a primary key from the Customer table. 
Does it check the edmx file?
How does it establish that ID is not a key from the Customer table?

```
    public class Order {
public int ID { get; set; }
public int CustomerId { get; set; }  // <-- Customer ID
public Customer Customer { get; set; } // <-- Customer object
...}
```

Comment: You specified DBFirst, so why EF shouldn't be able to derive such information from DB schema?

Comment: _"Does it check the edmx file? "_ - yes.

Answer (score 0):

The information is located in the model's edmx file XML.  You can view this by right clicking on your model in Solution Explorer, clicking on Open With, and selecting XML (Text) Editor.  The section you will be looking for will appear similar to the below example code.

```
<Association Name="FK_MYFOREIGNKEY">
   <End Role="Customer" Type="Self.Customer" Multiplicity="0..1" />
   <End Role="Order" Type="Self.Order" Multiplicity="*" />
   <ReferentialConstraint>
      <Principal Role="Customer">
         <PropertyRef Name="CustomerId" />
      </Principal>
      <Dependent Role="Order">
         <PropertyRef Name="CustomerId" />
      </Dependent>
   </ReferentialConstraint>
</Association>
```

Comment: So to confirm, entity framework sees public Customer Customer and then checks the rest of the properties within the Order class to see if they located in the edmx?

Would it only check properties that have the models name within its name? i.e. it would only check for customerId in the customer model

Comment: Not exactly.  Some of these relationships are also contained in the model's template file, i.e. model.tt.  If you expand the hierarchy below this file, you will notice a list of source files with the same names as your tables.  When you open the file for Customer, you will notice that there an Order property, and if you open Order, you will see a Customer property.  Depending on how you have your database structured, you may have numerous relationships.  CustomerId may be located in several tables, and if so, these relationships will be defined here.